# I have trouble running this code on my project react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner on react and I am reading the official documentation to have a good base, except that when I execute the examples given on codeopen it works but I do not know how to make it work on my project.

this example https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/zKRGpo?editors=0010

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

it works well on codepen but in my project it does not work. how to export this code on App for it to work.  sorry for my english

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Define "does not work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not done...

- Install node
- Install npm

In terminal

1. `npm install create-react-app -g`
2. `create-react-app <folder_name>`

Copy the code from sandbox to src folder

In terminal

```
npm run start
```

Comment: Please have a look at the README file at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app to setup

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

> Note: I’m assuming you already installed node and npm on your machine

```
npx create-react-app appname
```

edit App.js/Index.js in src folder and add your code

to run your project

```
npm start
```

Comment: Please remove one of your answers; you can edit an answer to include additional information--but two answers from a single person isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is follow this:

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

this will give you a guide on how to start a react App

Are you receiving any errors when running the code?

it could be a number of reasons why it is not working

Make sure you have

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

At the top of the file you are editing

Also maybe go through a few youtube tutorials on React so it gives you a basic understanding on structure set up, creating new components, passing props, state etc..

I always find Traversy Media explains topics quite well:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBws8MSXN7A

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

i think you need to import react and react-dom on your project like this

Comment: Note: I’m assuming you already installed node and npm on your machine

Comment: Please remove one of your answers; you can edit an answer to include additional information--but two answers from a single person isn't necessary.